# For Astro.js, how do I inject page content (seo meta tags) into <head> section of an Astro layout?

Tags: javascript, html, astrojs

I've got an Astro.js layout file with a header, footer, and all the other things I want to appear on every page on my site. There are two areas (names slots) that I want to put page content into. One area in the  and one in the  (between the header and footer)

Roughly, this is my layout.astro:

```
---
import '../styles/global.styl'
import '../styles/page.styl'
---

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <slot name='head' />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a href="/">Company Name</a>
      <nav>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
        <a href="/about">About</a>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <slot name='body' />

    <footer>
      <p id="copyright">© {new Date().getFullYear()} Company Name</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
<html>
```

Those two slots (head and body) will receive content from my page. My page currently looks like this:

```
---
import Layout from '../layouts/page.astro'
import PageSeo from '../components/PageSeo.astro'

var { info = {} } = Astro.props
      info.title = '404 - Not Found'
      info.description = 'The page you requested could not be found. Please check the spelling of the URL.'
      info.image = 'image link'
      info.url = 'page url'
---

<Layout title={info.title}>

  <head slot='head'>
    <PageSeo page={info} />
  </head>

  <main slot='body'>

  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
  <p>Hm... You’ve arrived at a page that does not exist. Computers are a bit literal, try checking the spelling of the link you typed.</p>

  </main>

</Layout>
```

The body content slides in just fine, but the SEO content (or anything I try to inject in the head) does not. I can't think of a wrapper element in HTML that's acceptable in the head of the document.

Ideas?

Comment: I can see you actually answered your own question now before I managed to finish typing mine up. My bad and glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

saw your post on the Discord.

You just need to put the slot attribute on the component, instead of creating another `<head>` element. Like so:

```
<Layout title={info.title}>

  <PageSeo slot='head' page={info} />

  <main slot='body'>

  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
  <p>Hm... You’ve arrived at a page that does not exist. Computers are a bit literal, try checking the spelling of the link you typed.</p>

  </main>

</Layout>
```

I believe the way you were doing it created another head element.

Also there are a good few integrations for SEO in Astro which may save you some time! They do very similar things (and more). Check them out here:
https://astro.build/integrations/?search=&categories%5B%5D=performance%2Bseo

Answer (score 2):

Ah... figured it out:

```
<PageSeo slot='head' page={info} />
```

While the  wrapper cannot receive a slot name, embedded components can. Cool.